# prepareForSegue will not work

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a navigation controller for an inbox. When you click on a message in the table it goes to a detail view which is getting fed data through my prepareForSegue method.

I have a bar button at the top "compose" a new message.

The button has worked the entire time until I put in the prepareForSegue method in and it crashes when I press the button now. I debugged it and it says it's because of the prepareForSegue method. I can click on the message in the tableview and it will go to the detail view and display all the information correctly but the button will not work now.

Here is the code for the prepareForSegue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];

    messageDetails * dvc = segue.destinationViewController;

    messages * currentMessage = [messagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    dvc.subject = currentMessage.subjectMessage;
    dvc.body = currentMessage.bodyMessage;
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
2013-04-22 18:24:22.107 GreekConnect[3904:c07] -[newmessageController setSubject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7558f30
2013-04-22 18:24:22.108 GreekConnect[3904:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[newmessageController setSubject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7558f30'
```

Comment: Have you checked to see what type of object dvc is?  It could be as simple as you not setting the class on the view controller to which you want to navigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common practice is that you check the segue for the identifier to ensure the segue you are "preparing" for is the one you intended.  You may want to put this check in to ensure that your prepareForSegue: is not getting called multiple times or from a place you didn't expect/intend.

Comment: That worked! Needed an if statement to check for the identifier. I had two segues for that view controller so I'm guessing it got confused!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the "subject" correctly declared and synthesized in your newmessageController class?

What I don't understand is if you have two different segues one to a particular ViewController (one for a new message and another for viewing the details of an existing one) or you're reusing the same newmessageController.